# Rundeck time format

Tags: rundeck

In the "Activity for jobs' page in Rundeck the execution time has a relative time field (example: "Today at 10:15 AM" or "Last Sunday at 4:51 AM") after the timestamp.
It is easy to change the date format of the timestamp by adding jobslist...format[.ko] in the i18n/messages.properties file.
It seems impossible however to change the format of the relative time message. It seems to be hard-coded in en_US with AM/PM which doesn't look too good in in non-English-speaking countries. The format is always the same regardless of the ?lang=xx parameter or the default language in the browser. Interestingly, other objects (like hovering over the field with the mouse and the duration get translated).
Has anyone successfully changed this?
[Example. See the duration field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJGnc.png)

I have been trying this with the docker images (4.8.0, 4.9.0 and SNAPSHOT)
I've looked at the source code and apparently this lies somewhere in the moment.js code.

Answer (score 0):

In some parts, the date formats are hard coded as you say, please add your use case on this [thread](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6582).

Comment: Thanks. 
I've added my comments to this thread. Is there any (ugly or not) workaround for this? Can this field be disabled for example?